# How to handle TYPE(*PNAME) in command source definition

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, control-language

1. How to make a TYPE(*PNAME) parameter be:

   - Required
   - Have a Default value
   - Have an initial length of 10
2. How to handle increases in the length of the prompted field,

   - The length of a prompted field of the type *PNAME can be increased with "&".
   - RPGLE needs to be the command processing program (CPP)

> **Example, command source definition:**
>
> ```
> PARM   KWD(PCML) TYPE(*PNAME) LEN(10) MIN(0) DFT(*MYDFT) SPCVAL((*MYDFT)) PROMPT('PCML Input path')
> ```

Comment: A *CMD parameter cannot be both required and have a DFT() value. Because it has a default value, it makes no sense also to make the parameter "required" since it cannot be missing. The CPP wouldn't care if the length was increased during prompting; it would always define the maximum length anyway and either receive a full fixed-length value or a variable-length value.

Comment: INLPMTLEN + LEN(512), FTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use the `MIN` option to make the parameter required.
- Use the `DFT` and `SPCVAL` options to specify default and special values.
- Use the `LEN` option to specify the maximum length.
- Use the `INLPMTLEN` option to specify the initial length.
- The command processing program must be defined to accept the maximum length.

**CMD**

```
PARM KWD(PCML) TYPE(*PNAME) LEN(512) DFT(*MYDFT) SPCVAL((*MYDFT)) 
  MIN(1) INLPMTLEN(10) PROMPT('PCML Input Path')
```

**RPG**

```
C     *ENTRY        PLIST                                      
C                   PARM                    PCML            512
```

For more information see the [Parameter Definition](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/parm.htm) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Been a steep learning curve. The command source definition documentation on the IBM i Knowledge Center is disappointing. [My preferred documentation is for V5R2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/c415721513.htm), it covers concepts rather than keywords. LFMF, remember F4 prompting.

Comment: But `DFT(*MYDFT)` and `MIN(1)` together will give a CPD6232 SEV(40) diagnostic compile error. The error is also reported in SEU when put into source. Is there a workaround?